# how to get working a multi-domain 301 redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cross-domain, http-status-code-301

We have some trouble with getting a redirect within a .htaccess working as we like. The issue is that we have 1 webroot for multiple websites. Now we want to setup a redirect rule for domain1 only.

```
Redirect 301 http://www.DOMAIN1.nl/aanbiedingen/2289/ http://www.DOMAIN1.nl/nederland/gelderland/
```

when calling http://www.DOMAIN1.nl/aanbiedingen/2289/ in the browser it ignore the rule.

changing the htaccess rule to:

```
Redirect 301 /aanbiedingen/2289/ http://www.DOMAIN1.nl/nederland/gelderland/
```

will trigger the redirect, but will trigger the rule also for DOMAIN2 and DOMAIN3.

Hopefully you can help me the let the redirect work as should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by checking that `HTTP_HOST` matches your domain before proceeding with the redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.DOMAIN1.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^aanbiedingen/2289/$ http://www.DOMAIN1.nl/nederland/gelderland/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not working 100%. Works with a single domain, but not with alias domainnames. As www.DOMAIN2.nl == www.DOMAIN1.nl.

Comment: you have stated that you `want to setup a redirect rule for domain1 only.` and nothing about aliases was specified. you can have my downvote now.

Comment: Figured out the issue. For each RewriteRule a set of RewriteCond was needed.